# How to configure bluetooth 4.0 device as a iBeacon Transmitter in windows

Tags: bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, ibeacon

I've configured iPhone 4s as a iBeacon Transmitter and I've received data from my Android application. Now I want to configure my bluetooth 4.0 device in windows. Is that possible? I've googled it but I couldn't find anything.

Comment: IBeacon will send it's data through Bluetooth protocol wich means any BT 4 enabled device receiver will inercept the data so with you can design a simple program to get the data or use some shareware

Comment: I've pluged in bluetooth device to my pc and my android application is searching ibeacons. But bluetooth device does not act like ibeacon. My question is how can bluetooh device act like ibeacon device. I've solved this problem in iOS, I had written a code and my iPhone 4s is sending ibeacons but I want to do same thing for windows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does your computer support Bluetooth smart ? Mobile operating systems including iOS, Android, Windows Phone and BlackBerry, as well as OS X, Linux, and Windows 8, natively support Bluetooth Smart.

EDIT

Unfortunately it's not currently supported under Windows 8.1.
check this link [Beacon Windows](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowshardware/en-US/a34dedb7-569b-4d86-98e5-fc206bcf5eb8/is-it-possible-to-discover-bluetooth-le-beacons-in-windows-881?forum=wdk)

Comment: My OS is Windows 8.1. I think I have to configure something after pluged-in bluetooth device. But I don't know what I have to do.

Comment: Oh, thanks for help, what about other Windows Operating systems? Do you know which one supports ibeacon?

Comment: Yep windows 8 not 8.1, can you accept my answer so it can help others

Comment: I will accept. Now, after I plug my bluetooth device to windows 8 pc then will it automatically become ibeacon transmitter?

Comment: I never tried it with w8 but normally it should do so

Comment: But if it would be like that, android or ios devices which have bluetooth 4.0 can transmit without any code. But I've written code for iOS then it became a transmitter.

Comment: If you're familiar with csharp you can bt and make your own

Answer (score 0):

The managed C# library [WinBeacon](https://www.nuget.org/packages/WinBeacon/) can be used for this purpose. It implements a simple HCI layer that talks directly to the BT4.0 dongle through a WinUSB driver (instead of the default Bluetooth driver).